# What are examples of services that track content-driven activity on social networks like Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: content, tracking, analytics

I'm trying to design the basics for a platform that enables users to access sets of statistics and information related to the way how their publications are handled and shared across social networks like Facebook and Twitter.

Many services are based on the contents published from the social networks themselves (e.g. [ThinkUp](http://thinkupapp.com/) and [Hootsuite](http://hootsuite.com/)), other are inspired on the traffic metrics (e.g. [Google Analytics](http://analytics.google.com), [Mint](http://www.haveamint.com/) and [Newsbeat](http://chartbeat.com/newsbeat/)).

I'm looking for fairly known examples of web analytics services that track social network activity, at least on Facebook and Twitter. Not just the good old analytics (I'm talking about the last examples I gave above), but the ones that focus on the contents and how they're handled by the community. These are some of the features I'm looking for:

- List of most commented, shared or liked publications;
- List of most active *sharers*;
- Variation of average "sharing activity" across last day, week, month;

Which services can do this? Are they web based applications or self-hosted apps? Do they have their own APIs? Can they track contents-driven activity instead of the plain old

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:

For **Twitter** you have Topsy trackbacks:

- http://topsy.com/stackoverflow.com/?bookmarket_ver=1.1
- http://topsy.com/twitter/stackwebmasters
- http://topsy.com/s/stack+exchange

(Topsy has an API)

And for **Facebook** you have Insights:

- http://www.facebook.com/insights/

For **Google+** +1's you have Webmaster tools:

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/social-activity?hl=en&siteUrl=http://www.yourdomain.net/

For **blogs** I use Google Blog seach.

And for **all websites** Google webmasters.